# Perform a contains-ignore-case with multiple search-tokens

Tags: strings, clojure

I had a look on Stack Overflow etc. on how to perform a contains ignore case with n given strings. Most answers suggested using regex for this task. Although it's a valid option, I prefer doing upper-case for both strings and apply a `.contains` afterwards.

The solution I came up with looks like this:

```
(defn desc-matches? [desc search-tokens] 
  (let [upper-desc (str/upper-case desc)
        upper-tokens (map str/upper-case search-tokens)]
    (some (partial #(.contains %1 %2) upper-desc) upper-tokens)))
```

Since I am relatively new to clojure, I'd appreciate if someone could have a look and tell me his/her thoughts on it.

**UPDATE 1 - Applied Thumbnails suggestion**

```
(defn desc-matches? [desc search-tokens] 
  (let [upper-desc (str/upper-case desc)
        upper-tokens (map str/upper-case search-tokens)]
    (some #(.contains upper-desc %) upper-tokens)))
```

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: `(partial #(.contains %1 %2) upper-desc)` is just `#(.contains upper-desc %)`.